# How to create an element with ref and then append it as a child element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to append a div elemnent to Parent, Parent was a highly encapsulated component and i can only get it's ref, now i create an element use `React.createElement()` because i can create ref for the element at the same time, then i tried to append this element to Parent with `appendChild()` but failed.

```
const demo: React.FC = () => {
    const parentRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

    // append child
    const childRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null)
    let child = React.createElement("div",{ref:childRef})

    useEffect(() =>{
        if(parentRef.current) {
            parentRef.current.appendChild(child)  // error
        }
    },[])

    return (
        <>
            <Parent
              ref={parentRef}
              {...allprops}
            />
        </>
    )
};
export default demo;
```

i got an error: Argument of type 'DetailedReactHTMLElement<HTMLAttributes, HTMLElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.

if i create child element with `let child = document.createElement("div")`, this error will not occur, but i can’t create ref for the child (or i don’t know how to).

What can i do to fix it? thank you in advance!

Comment: You should not use `appendChild` in react under any circumstances

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are attempting to insert React components into another component that you only have a DOM reference for.

The issue with your provided code is that `React.createElement()` creates a React Element that is used within React's Virtual DOM and `HTMLElement.appendChild()` expects a normal DOM node.

You might be able to achieve this via portals:

1. Use `parentRef` to insert a DOM node ('child').
2. Store reference to DOM node in `childRef`.
3. Use `childRef` as the container for a portal.

NOTE: The below code is untested but should point you in the rough direction if you wish to pursue it further.

```
const InsertedContent: React.FC = ({ container, children }) => {
    if (!container) {
        return null;
    }

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        children, 
        container
    );
}

const demo: React.FC = () => {
    const parentRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

    const childRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null)

    useEffect(() =>{
        if(parentRef.current) {
            const child = document.createElement('div');
            childRef.current = child;
            parentRef.current.appendChild(child);
        }
    },[])

    return (
        <>
            <Parent
              ref={parentRef}
              {...allprops}
            />
            <InsertedContent container={childRef.current}>
                This is some content to stick into the child.
            </InsertedContent>
        </>
    )
};

export default demo;
```

Comment: Thank you! but I had given up to modify that component, it was much better to create a new one instead of forcibly adding a new node to the original component. Anyway,thanks for your advice, I believe it will be helpful in the future.